# Modernizr detecting IE11 as not supporting email input type

Tags: email, modernizr, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Modernizr in an app, and it is rejecting the email input type in IE11 and keeps changing the type to text. This is an issue because I'm relying on the email type to be there for validation. I'm under the impression that the email input type should be perfectly valid in IE11. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Is this an issue with Modernizr, or does anyone have any suggestions on what I might try?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: which version of modernizr - I am not able to replicate the issue (http://cl.ly/image/230M152h1S2f)

Comment: I'm using the latest. But that's a good point. I tried the test suite, and it also passed for the email type. Yet it still isn't working within the app. I'll have to dig around and see if there's any other code that could be causing this.

Comment: could you open up the F12 dev tools and check the value of `Modernizr.inputtypes.email` ?

Comment: [image](http://i57.tinypic.com/ok1p47.png)

It's coming up as false within the app.

Comment: could you open a bug report on the modernizr github issue tracker?

Comment: what document mode are you using? IE could be falling back to an earlier version.

Comment: David, you're right. It was defaulting to IE9 compatibility mode. Thanks!